# How to copy all the row data from one table to another in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to copy all the rows and columns from one table to another. I know the way using Cursor, The cursor gets all the data and i then taking it into the ArrayList and after doing the same thing reverse to insert it into another table.

But is there any simple and fast way to copy one table to another. If **Yes**,then please let me know..

Comment: Did you try any of [these](https://www.google.co.in/search?cx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=copy+date+from+one+table+to+another+sqlite+android&safe=on#hl=en&safe=active&sa=X&ei=vikSUN72EMvKrAemqoG4CA&ved=0CGwQvwUoAQ&q=copy+data+from+one+table+to+another+sqlite+android&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=504d8e940f50c67&biw=1440&bih=775)?

Comment: yes. i have taken data into arraylist through the cursor. and after that i inserted that arraylist data into another table. Is there any way to transfer the data directly from the cursor to the database??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the contents of one table and use it to populate another table as long the structure of the tables are same. `INSERT INTO Destination SELECT * FROM Source;`

Comment: but i have bit confusion. this works fine when i am inserting into sqlite browser. But i am not able to do the same through the android code.Can you suggest me anu way to do this????